# Recombine characters strings and separate initals with a period using R and Regex

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

I have a list of authors that are all slightly formatted differently. My goal is to extract the different components of every character string. The different components are:

- initials (usually all capital letters followed by a period
- last name (all words that start with a capital letter)
- If present, prefixes of last name (all words that consist only of lowercase characters)

Next I want to put everything back together so that every author and list of authors are formatted in the exact same way. I prefer a solution using stringr.

Below is a small sample of my dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)

sample_list <- structure(list(Id = c(22667, 33807, 3625, 35531, 32051, 27721), auteur = c("van Bar, A.J.M.",  "de Vogel, J.J., R. Robbing, M.J. Smit & H.L.T. Bergsma-John", "Stark, M. ten", "Eeden, F.W. van", "Bouman, F. & F.D. Parker", "Sullock Enzlin, R.A.F. & J. Hoenselaar"),      jaartal = c(1938, 2016, 2002, 1889, 1997, 1991)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Because a single character value can have multiple authors, I first split the data so that every row refers to a single name. Then, using several regex statements, I extract the different components of each name. See below for my code so far.

```
sample_list |>
 mutate(
  auteur = str_remove(auteur, pattern = ",")) |>
 separate_longer_delim(cols = auteur, delim = regex("\\, | &"),) |>
 mutate(
  auteur = str_squish(auteur),
  initials = auteur |>  
              str_extract(pattern = "(\\b[A-Z\\.]+\\b)") |> 
              str_remove_all(pattern = "\\.") |> 
              str_squish(),     
  last_name = sapply(
               str_extract_all(string = auteur, pattern = "\\b\\p{Lu}(?:\\p{Lu}*\\p{lu})?\\w+"), 
               paste, collapse= ' '),  
  prefix = auteur |> 
            str_extract(pattern = "\\b[a-z](?:[a-z ]*[a-z])?\\b") |> 
            str_squish()
)
```

This works for me (also taking into account special characters as is common in Eastern or Nothern Europe), but I have trouble putting everything back together. I first need to standardise all the names. I want to do this by separting the initials by a period followed by the prefix (if present) and lastly the last name. For example:
"A.J.M. van Bar"
"J.J. de Vogel"
"R. Robbing"

**Expected output**

In the end every row needs to represent all the authors of a single publication (by using the Id-column) where all the authors are separated by a comma or '&' symbol depending on the number of authors. I prefer a solution using stringr. The final expected output should be something like:

"A.J.M. van Bar"

"J.J. de Vogel, R. Robbing, M.J. Smit & H.L.T. Bergsma John"

"M. ten Stark"

"F.W. van Eeden"

"F. Bouman & F.D. Parker"

"R.A.F. Sullock Enzlin & J. Hoenselaar"

Comment: do you have a few more examples? it seems like in your two examples, the only person whose name needs processing is the first name, and that is just flipping around the words

Comment: at least 6 total would be ideal

Comment: @Mark, I've updated my question and included some more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single line (albeit using a complex regex):

```
sample_list %>%
  mutate(auteur = str_replace_all(auteur, "([^,]+),\\s([A-Z]\\.[A-Z]\\.([A-Z]\\.)?(?=$|,\\s?))", "\\2 \\1"))
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     Id auteur                                                     jaartal
  <dbl> <chr>                                                        <dbl>
1 22667 A.J.M. van Bar                                                1938
2 33807 J.J. de Vogel, R. Robbing, M.J. Smit & H.L.T. Bergsma-John    2016
```

**How this works**:

Essentially what you do is divide the strings into two capture groups: the first for the family names plus suffix, the second for the initials, based on the constraint that the initials must be followed by either a comma or the end of the string, and finally use backreference `\\1` and `\\2` to flip the two components:

- `([^,]+)`: 1st capture group for any character occurring multiple times ***except*** a `,` (this is called a negative character class) to capture the family name plus suffix,
- `\\s`: intervening whitespace (which is omittted as it is not enclosed in the capturing groups)
- `([A-Z]\\.[A-Z]\\.([A-Z]\\.)?(?=$|,\\s?))`: 2nd capture group for initials; this expression falls into the following components:

-`[A-Z]\\.[A-Z]\\.([A-Z]\\.)?`: at least two and possibly three capital letter each followed by a dot, ***iff*** ...

-`(?=$|,\\s?)`: ... they are followed by either a comma plus optional whitespace or end of string position (this constraint is imposed by a positive lookahead `(?=...)`)

Comment: I have added more examples to better show the range of ways of how authors could be listed. When I run your code it doesn't work for the other examples. But I like the way you reduced my code to just a single regex!

Comment: I've been playing around a while; this solution gets all but one string right: `sample_list %>%
  mutate(auteur = str_replace_all(auteur, "([^,]+),\\s([^,&]+(?=$|,|\\s))", "\\2 \\1"))`. Perhaps you can adjust it further...

Answer (score 0):

Chris' answer already helped a lot and is a fast and quite elegant way of tackling my problem. Below you can find an alternative solution that I come up with so far, partly helped and inspired by Chris' solution. Note that Chris' answer is also better in terms of raw speed. I think my answer below can be more flexible if you would require a different kind of output, but perhaps it would be better to edit Chris' original answer.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

sample_list |> 
      mutate(
        auteur = str_remove(auteur, pattern = ",")) |> 
          separate_longer_delim(cols = auteur, 
                                delim = regex("\\, | &"),
                                ) |> 
          mutate(
            auteur = str_squish(auteur),
            first_name = auteur |> # This regex is to capture the initials
              str_extract(pattern = "[A-Z](\\s|\\.|-)([[A-Z]\\.]+)?") |> 
              str_replace_all(pattern = "\\s", replacement = ".") |>
              str_squish(),
            tussenvoegsel = auteur |> # This regex is to capture only lowercase words
              str_extract(pattern = "\\b[a-z](?:[a-z ]*[a-z])?\\b") |> 
              str_squish(),
            last_name = auteur |> # Here I basically remove all the words that were captured in the previous two statements
              str_remove_all(pattern = glue::glue("{first_name}|{tussenvoegsel}")) |> 
              str_squish(),
            full_name = case_when( # Two different ways of pasting the names together
              is.na(tussenvoegsel) ~ glue::glue("{first_name} {last_name}"),
              TRUE ~ glue::glue("{first_name} {tussenvoegsel} {last_name}")
            )
          ) |> 
          select(Id, full_name) |> 
          group_by(Id) |> # Grouping by Id to then add all the diffent authors together
          summarise(
            auteur = glue::glue_collapse(full_name, sep = ", ", last = " & ")
          )
```